# Trend Micro Anti-Virus / Deep Security Unattended Installation

Tags: powershell, automation, anti-virus, msi

I would greatly appreciate if someone with operational knowledge about Trend Micro Deep Security, could verify or debunk the following statement:

> The software cannot be installed unattended client-side, due to the server-side software have no way of automatically detecting new installations.
>
> In effect this means that each client-side installation of the Anti-Virus software can only be installed manually by an operator logging into the client-side machine and then subsequently logging in to the server-side gui and finalizing the installation.
>
> This is, allegedly, due to "the terms of the license and missing functionality server-side".

Or put in another way: Is it really true that this enterprise level software can only be installed manually with a number of human gui interactions for each client machine - or am I being fed bullshit from our off-shore team in order for them to retain a pr. installation extra fee?

Comment: My vote is for [total bullshit.](https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/10/0/Add-Computers/ug-add-dep-scripts.html)

Comment: @MichaelHampton make it into an answer so i can give you the points.
Thanks for finding what I couldnt.